# How i can use pinescript for STOCKTRADE?

Tags: stock, pine-script

I have pinescript trade strategy with code.
How can i use this pinescript code for stocktrade ?

Or how can i convert pinescript to other programming languages ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any platform able to use native Pine code, nor of any automated conversion tool. Afaik, conversion needs to be done manually.